# Regex to not have a sequence of repeated characters

Tags: regex

I have a regex `/(.)\1{1,2}/` that matches the text that has sequence of repeated characters.

But I want a regex that does the opposite. I don't want to negate it. How do can I do that?

Comment: Please, clarify the question, given `abcdefghaa` do you want just to check that it doesn't have repeated characters, or do you want to extract `abcdefgha` from it? If you just want to check, you can use the following regex: `^(?!.*(.)\1).+$`

Comment: For instance if I enter a value "aabbcdef", this should return false and "aaabbcdef" must return true. As the first value has repeated sequence but repeated only twice. While the other value has more than two times repeated letters.

Comment: @AnushaSwaminathan here it is http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/3

Comment: No, it isn't working :-(

Comment: @AnushaSwaminathan could you add some more explanation?

Comment: If you don't want to negate it, perhaps this http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/4

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!(.)\1{1,2}).
```

or you can try

```
(.)(?!\1)
```

You can try this.This uses a negative lookahead.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/8

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be possible without negation,

```
(.)(?:(?!\1).){1,2}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/1)

The below regex would capture the first character and checks for more than two repeated characters. If there are more than two repeated characters at the start, it won't match that string.

```
^(.)\1(?:(?!\1).)+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/3)

Comment: Thank you, but this is validating "bbbbark". Even if one letter repeats sequencially more than twice, it should return false. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/10 . And this http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/2 would allow only two repeated characters.

Answer (score -4):

You can try this

```
"^(?!.*(.)\1).{0,11}$"
```

Comment: Why should I, or anyone else for that matter, "try this"? Instead of dumping bare code, **explain** why the code works. Either in text around, or comments within the code.